# Empty Java scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to make a scanner that cannot be empty. So when enter is pressed while there is nothing in the scanner i want to make a warning message. I have this piece of code.

```
  if (user_input.hasNext())// only if scanner is empty and enter is pressed{
        System.out.println("Scanner can not be empty");
    }
```

Comment: Read the whole line.  If there's nothing in it, print your warning.

Comment: What, do you think, would the "man off the street" think if he were presented with this error message? - Perhaps "Please type the data [...] before pressing the "enter" key" would be more adequate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    if(input.isEmpty())
    {
      System.out.println("Scanner can not be empty");
    }
```